# Content sections for custom style window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, window

Greeting, i have a window with custom style (that includes custom template), but now i want to define some sections in my window template layout, for example - window title bar, window content (the default place for items) and window footer, so i can then use it like this (or similar):

```
<Window Style="{StaticResource CustomWindow}">
    <Window.Header>
        <Grid x:Name="HeaderGrid">
        </Grid>
    </Window.Header>
    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid">
    </Grid>
    <Window.Footer>
        <Grid x:Name="FooterGrid">
        </Grid>
    </Window.Footer>
</Window>
```

i thought i have to add corresponding dependency properties to .xaml.cs file of the style dictionary that contains my window style, but it's class is not inherited from anything, so it is not a DependencyObject, i tried adding dependency properties to the window that uses the style, so i can just bind ContentPresenters from template to it, but it does not allow to set the content of those properties from window's xaml, so, is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: If you want custom content, use `ContentControl`s.  Have default `DataTemplate`s based on the type of Content you put into those `ContentControl`s

Comment: @Joe i'm familiar with ContentControls, but i didn't really understand your idea to be honest, can you please share some code sample where custom window template contains several ContentControls and you can selectively fill them from the window's xaml?

Comment: In order to set a Window.Header and Window.Footer, the Window class would need to have those properties. You would have to derive a class from Window or declare attached properties.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to add a grid as root panel to the Window. Define three rows or one for each section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to enable the usage of your example you should create a custom base class from which all your windows can inherit.

Define the default layout of the base class `SectionWindow`. Simply define the related default `Style` in the */Themes/Generic.xaml* file:

**Generic.xaml**

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SectionWindow}">
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
          Value="Stretch" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
          Value="Stretch" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:SectionWindow">
        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
          <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <!-- Dynamic content header row -->
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
              <!-- Dynamic content row -->
              <RowDefinition />
              <!-- Dynamic content footer row -->
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0"
                              ContentSource="Header"
                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />

            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"
                              ContentSource="Content"
                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />

            <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="2"
                              ContentSource="Footer"
                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
          </Grid>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then define the base class. This is a basic example. It's recommended to define corresponding template properties for each section property. For example, the `Header` property should have an associated `HeaderTemplate` dependency property of type `DataTemplate`. Because the `ContentPresenter` in the default `Style` use the `ContentPresenter.ContentSource` property, the template will be automatically mapped.

For the `Content` property, we can reuse the inherited `Window.Content` property.

**SectionWindow.cs**

```cs
public class SectionWindow : Window
{
  public object Header
  {
    get => (object)GetValue(HeaderProperty);
    set => SetValue(HeaderProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Header", 
    typeof(object), 
    typeof(SectionWindow), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public object Footer
  {
    get => (object)GetValue(FooterProperty);
    set => SetValue(FooterProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty FooterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Footer",
    typeof(object),
    typeof(SectionWindow),
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  static SectionWindow() => DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(SectionWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(SectionWindow)));
}
```

Then you can use the new window `SectionWindow` as follows:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : SectionWindow
{
  public ExampleWindow() 
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<local:SectionWindow x:Class="Net.Wpf.MainWindow" ...>
  <local:SectionWindow.Header>
    <Border Background="Red">
      <TextBlock Text="Header content" />
    </Border>
  </local:SectionWindow.Header>

  <local:SectionWindow.Content>
    <Border Background="Green">
      <TextBlock Text="Window content" />
    </Border>
  </local:SectionWindow.Content>

  <local:SectionWindow.Footer>
    <Border Background="Blue">
      <TextBlock Text="Footer content" />
    </Border>
  </local:SectionWindow.Footer>
</local:SectionWindow>
```

Comment: but how do i change the base class of MainWindow if it's partial?

Comment: What do you mean? This example is pretty much complete. You can derive Mainwindow from any Window. In this example MainWindow extends SectionWindow. SectionWindow itself extends Window.

Comment: `partial` only means that a class definition is spread across multiple files. In this case this file is a .xaml file. On C# level a partial class behaves like a normal class.

Comment: oh, i missed the fact that you create SectionWindow in MainWindow.xaml instead of MainWindow, i though it's impossible to change base type of auto-generated part of partial window class, thanks

Comment: This is the common XAML element tree rule. The root element is always the base class. The actual custom type e.g. `MainWindow` can't be the root element (unless `MainWindow`. itself is used as a base class). And with the `x:Class` on the root element directive you define the derived partial class.

Comment: For example, you use ´Window` as root element because it is the base class of `MainWindow`. You use `UserControl` as the root element, because `MyUserControl` derives from it. You use `Page` as the root element because `MyPage` derives from it. You use `SectionWindow` as the element root, because it is the new base class of `MainWindow`.

Comment: This means you can follow the same pattern when extending `UserControl` to create a new user control base class. This works with any type that WPF allows to be the root of the element tree. As long as this type (a `FrameworkElement`) knows how to handle children of type `Visual` it can be a root element.

Comment: lol, how have i never noticed it... it makes perfect sense now, thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You could create `CustomControl` that derives from `Window`, like so

```
public class CustomWindow : Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(object), typeof(CustomWindow));
    public object Header
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FooterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Footer", typeof(object), typeof(CustomWindow));
    public object Footer
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(FooterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FooterProperty, value); }
    }

    static CustomWindow()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomWindow)));
    }
}
```

with `Style` for it like so

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomWindow}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomWindow}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <!-- Header -->
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"/>

                        <!-- Content -->
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>

                        <!-- Footer -->
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="2" Content="{TemplateBinding Footer}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and here's example usage

```
<local:CustomWindow x:Class="WpfApp10.MainWindow"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp10"
                    Title="MainWindow"
                    Width="800"
                    Height="450"
                    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <local:CustomWindow.Header>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red"/>
    </local:CustomWindow.Header>

    <local:CustomWindow.Footer>
        <Rectangle Fill="Blue"/>
    </local:CustomWindow.Footer>

    <Rectangle Fill="Green"/>
</local:CustomWindow>
```

don't forget to change base class to `CustomWindow` for `MainWindow.xaml.cs`